# Ember js to work with HATEOAS REST API

Tags: ember.js, spring-hateoas

I have a REST endpoint `"http://localhost:8080/customers"` which I would like to hook to my Ember JS app.

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
revision: 12,
adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
url: 'http://localhost:8080/customers'
})
});
```

REST Payload

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/customers/search"
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "customers" : [ {
      "id" : 2,
      "firstName" : "Jim",
      "lastName" : "Smith",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/customers/2"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "id" : 1,
      "firstName" : "Jimmy",
      "lastName" : "Jones",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/customers/1"
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

I keep on getting this error.  This is my second week on Ember JS.  To be honest this is a lot harder than I imagined.  Not very easy to debug or understand.

Error while loading route:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at App.CustomersRoute.Ember.Route.extend.model
```

Comment: That's a really old version of Ember Data, please include your route and model definitions.

Comment: Now, I am getting new errors. Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/73/edit here's a template for showing what you're doing, so we can hopefully find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to transform your data into this format using a custom serializer:

```
{
  "customers" : [ 
    {
      "id" : 2,
      "firstName" : "Jim",
      "lastName" : "Smith"
    }, {
      "id" : 1,
      "firstName" : "Jimmy",
      "lastName" : "Jones"
    } 
  ]
}
```

You'll want to read https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md which explains how to use `extractSingle`, `extractArray`, `normalize`, `normalizeHash`.

You're particular example looks close to the api's example: 
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extractArray

```
App.CustomerSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
  extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
    // do your own implementation and return that, or modify it slightly
    // and do the default implementation
    return this._super(store, type, payload);
  },
});
```